# How can I create an array from the value of the same directive on different pages in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using Angular 1.5.7 and am trying to see if I can push the value of an attribute within a directive used on several different pages to an array that lives in the controller.

I am pretty sure that I need to used transclusion in order to do this but I am stuck. Below is a simplified version of what I have so far:

**about.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl"
  <div cd-header mypage="About">
    <div>About Page</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**contact.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl"
  <div cd-header mypage="Contact">
    <div>Contact Page</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**header.html**

```
<div>{{mypage}}
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

**cd-header.js**

```
var cdHeader = function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      mypage: "@"
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'header.html',
    link: function(scope) {
      // Not sure but I think I might need a function here
    }
  }
}

module.exports = cdHeader;
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope) {
  var nav = [];
  // Not sure how items that are pushed to the nav get to this point
}

module.exports = MainCtrl;
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", [
  'about',
  'contact',
])
  .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
  .directive('cdHeader', cdHeader)
```

I am able to get the value of the `mypage` attribute in the directive as well as its transcluded `<div>` to appear in the header but only for the current page in view.

The part I am missing is how to get all of the `mypage` values from each page into the header regardless of the current page in view. I am somewhat new to Angular and have read a lot but have not come across anything that explains how this can be done. Maybe this is achieved with a service? If so, I'm not sure how to go about it.

To clarify with a visual. This is what I see:

[image]

But this is what I want to see:

[image]

Comment: Really not clear exactly what you are looking for. Also need to be aware that each `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` will create a new instance of that controller and each instance will have it's own new scope

Comment: My go-to approach to share stuff between directives is declaring a bag service.

Comment: @charlietfl, I've added a visual to make it more clear. And what you've said about new instances of controllers may make what I am trying to do impossible. Ultimately, I want to create a nav of items built from the pages themselves. If I have five pages, I want five nav items built automatically.

Comment: are all of these in the main page at the same time? if so it's quite doable using  a service. If you are using a router though and each represents  a different route then the array would only get built as each path was visited

Comment: I don't understand why you're using all these directives.  Can't you just have two links in your template?  It's not like any dynamic behavior is needed.

Comment: Or if you're trying to change the contents of the header in different places with arguments, don't both with all the transclude stuff; just declare an isolate scope and pass in the options.

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly pointed out, there are several ways to do it.

Perhaps you can pass the array from the MainCtrl as an attribute to the directive. For instance, nav-array="nav". However, before that, you need to set the array nav as such

```
var $scope = this;
this.nav = [];
```

The second option is to consume a service. Create an angular service, pass it as a dependency in the directive, and consume it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a constant; the directive can set something in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create an array in `MainCtrl` as `$scope.headers = ['about':'About','contact':'Contact','home':'Home']` or create a factory/service to share the headers data and in header.html use ng-repeat to display the header name according to myPage value like below

```
<div ng-repeat="page in headers[myPage]">{{page}}
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```